# when an RWMutex Unlock which blocked goroutine will be waked up

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

```
var mu sync.RWMutex

//goroutine 1
go func() {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
   //something else
}()
//goroutine 2
go func() {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    //something else
}()
//goroutine 3
go func() {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    //something else
}()
//goroutine 4
go func() {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()
    //something else
}()
```

goroutine 1 now get the lock, goroutine 2,3,4 blocked.
when goroutine 1 release the lock, which goroutine will be waked up first? Randomly？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that locks eventually becomes available to writers, a blocked `Lock` call excludes new readers from acquiring the lock.  If goroutine 2 blocks on `Lock` before goroutine 3 blocks on `RLock`, then goroutine 2 will run before goroutine 3. The execution order is unspecified if goroutine 3 blocks on `RLock` before goroutine 2 blocks on `Lock`.

Comment: the code is just a sample, in my code , goroutine 1 will acquire the lock first，then  goroutines 2, 3, 4 blocked. When  goroutine 1 release the lock, goroutines 2,3 and 4 , which could get the lock first?

Comment: If goroutine 2 blocks before 3 and 4, then 2 will get the lock before 3 and 4. Otherwise, the order is unspecified.

Comment: you mean depending on  when the goroutine blocked?

Comment: seems that it cannot obtain a write lock until all existing read lock waiters have been granted.

Comment: @OneOfOne I see :)